# onResume() and onPause() is being called on the first launch

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am having an activity and on Launching the activity through Intent from one of my service, onCreate(), onPause() and onResume() is called.

I am not very sure where i am doing wrong, i have removed all the code, just the basic function codes are available, and also i have removed all the codes which were opening that particular activity, still the behaviour is same.

I am including the simplest code i am using

**ActivityClass.java**

```
public class ActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("TEST : onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        System.out.println("TEST : onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("TEST : onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**Service class**

```
public class OverlayService extends Service {

    Context context;
    public static final String TAG = OverlayService.class.getSimpleName();

    public OverlayService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public OverlayService() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[onCreateService]");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if(myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
            //it is locked
            showOverlayActivity();
        } else {
            //it is not locked
        }
        registerOverlayReceiver();
        context = this;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterOverlayReceiver();
        Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("ac.in.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void unregisterOverlayReceiver() {
        if (overlayReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(overlayReceiver);
        }
    }

    private static final String ACTION_DEBUG = "kunal.lockoverlay.action.DEBUG";

    private void registerOverlayReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_DEBUG);
        registerReceiver(overlayReceiver, filter);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver overlayReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "[onReceive]" + action);
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                // ACTON_SCREEN_ON
                showOverlayActivity();
            } else if (action.equals(ACTION_DEBUG)) {
                showOverlayActivity();
            }
        }
    };

    private void showOverlayActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, ActivityClass.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Can someone point some of the possible reasons for this behaviour or could identify where i am doing wrong?

Comment: what was the problem ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code but you need to study about `Activity Lifecycle`!

Comment: @NickBapu, what specifically i am missing in Activity Lifecycle, could you please specify?

Comment: @StavroXhardha, the problem is that once the activity is being created, onCreate(), onPause() and onResume() are being called, in that case only onCreate() is being expected to be called.

Comment: `onResume()` gets called, I don't know about the `onPause()` but if you don't need them just remove them from the file, why the big deal?

Comment: @StavroXhardha, i need them to perform some operation.

Answer (score 1):

Well everything will be called regardless, you have defined it in your `ClassName.java` file.

You override the method and define it in your class to perform certain action/function when that is called.

**For eg.,**

You could use `onResume` to clear an arraylist and add updated elements to arraylist **(OR)** dismiss all notifications from your app on moving to that activity, say

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    calendarList.clear();
//dismiss all notifications here
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager!=null)
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

**OR eg.,** `onDestroy` to destroy the bluetooth service,

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBluetoothService != null) {
            mBluetoothService.stop();
        }
     }
```

Hope that clarifies. Happy coding!

Comment: I couldn't get your point, as in i am using these methods to perform some specific tasks, but how is this connected with my current scenario? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Isn't your question why are `onPause` and `onResume` or `onDestroy` called even without you defining it?

Comment: I mean, onPause() is called when the user is not on the activity(maybe he has switched to some other app) and onResume() is called when the user comes back to the current activity, but my question is that why onPause() and onResume() are called when i am launching my activity for the first time, as in no such situation is there where onPause() and onResume() should be callled

Answer (score 0):

About service class, you should call `registerReceiver()` or initialize variables in `onCreate` instead of `onStartCommand` because `onCreate` is only called once at the first time of starting service and `onStartCommand` will be called every time you want to trigger an action to the service by calling `startService(Intent)`.